# FFMPEG Unable to find a suitable output format for '80'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to run ffmpeg with the following command

```
ffmpeg -r -n 80 -i /mnt/labserver/MD/Experimental_data/SS01054/U3_f/200206/111530_s4a10_p3-4/images_registered/on0/fly0/img_%d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 /mnt/labserver/MD/Experimental_data/SS01054/U3_f/200206/111530_s4a10_p3-4/resultsDLC/1.mp4
```

I am getting the following error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '80'                                                            80: Invalid argument
```

Could someone help what is wrong here?

Comment: What is `-r` meant for? `-n 80`?

Comment: Not sure, just trying to follow a template. I get the same error if I remove the -r.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if this is relevant, but I am trying to run this command through ssh.

Comment: Then remove `-r -n 80`

Comment: Thanks, this one works, but then how do I make sure to get 80 fps?

Comment: Add `-framerate 80` before `-i`